# Sign-in to Skype using SKYPE4COMLib

Tags: c#, skype

I am currently developing a client program for skype using C# and SKYPE4COMLib. But I couln't find a way to Sign-in to skype using SKYPE4COMLib. Is there a way to Sign-in to Skype(or Change the user) using SKYPE4COMLib??

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using Skypekit.NET to make client .NET skype applications.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330778/Skypekit-NET

---

An example of login:

```
public SkypeMain skypeMain;
public void Login(string user, string pass)
{
    skypeMain = new SkypeMain();
    if ((!skypeMain.myAppKeyPairMgr.resolveAppKeyPairPath()) ||
        (!skypeMain.myAppKeyPairMgr.isValidCertificate()))
    {
        return;
    }

    skypeMain.mySession.doCreateSession(skypeMain.MY_CLASS_TAG, user, skypeMain.myAppKeyPairMgr.getPemFilePathname());

    if (skypeMain.mySession.mySignInMgr.Login(skypeMain.MY_CLASS_TAG, skypeMain.mySession, pass))
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```